# Skipping request node.js

Tags: node.js, request, skip

I have urlARRAY that has some urls.
I did a loop and I did request to urls in the array one by one.
Some sites in urlARRAY are loading slow. Can I skip these?

```
var req = require('request');

urlARRAY.forEach(function(url) {
    req(url, function (error, response, html) {


        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("success");
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have my permission to skip those.

Comment: @idbehold, I did not understand?

Comment: In fact URL loading is done asynchronously here. This means code is not waiting for next url before first one is loaded. You can also reduce `timeout` parameter for request. So you'll get error faster.